# MySQL DB Migration fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

For a wordpress website I am trying to migrate the website and MySQL database. Although when I import it, it gives me an error. I no longer have access to the old one.

```
 Error
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you trying to import it through WordPress, from the command-line, or from another tool?

Comment: Where its is showing error in mySql or on front end?

Comment: What tool are you using for the import?

Comment: ChrisForrence I am trying to import it through my localhost PHPMyAdmin

RahulSharma I think in MySQL

Comment: ___#1046 - No database selected___ Should have been a bit of a clue. Add a `USE \`DATABASE_NAME\`;` at the top of this script.So that MYSQL knows which database you are trying to create the table in

Comment: Octavian I just do it via PHPMyAdmin

Comment: RiggsFolly I think that might have fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Did you fix it in the end?

Comment: Yep, this is fixed now. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## 1046 - No database selected Should have been a bit of a clue. Add a USE `DATABASE_NAME`; at the top of this script. So that MYSQL knows which database you are trying to create the table in
>
> – RiggsFolly